# System.NullReference in DisplayModeProvider

Tags: mobile, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to show desktop view when user uses *Ipad*.
I use **DisplayModeProvide**, but sometimes Elmah keep this error:
**System.NullReferenceException:** *in System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.GetDisplayInfoForVirtualPath*

This is my code:

```
   if (DisplayModeProvider.Instance != null)
    if (DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes != null)
      DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("")
      {
        ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf
            ("iPad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
      });
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue, try checking for a null `UserAgent`

```
if (DisplayModeProvider.Instance != null)
    if (DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes != null)
      DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("")
      {
        ContextCondition = (context => context.Request.UserAgent != null && context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf
            ("iPad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
      });
```

Comment: Thanks @robmzd    
I solved with:    
  
`// Ipad  
      var userAgent = Request.UserAgent;  
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAgent) && (userAgent.IndexOf("iPad") > -1))  
        HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(BrowserOverride.Desktop);`